# How to manage config for AMP auto-ads in AdSense/DFP?

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to use amp [auto-ads](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-auto-ads) feature, but could not find a way to add/edit [configuration object](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-auto-ads#configuration-spec) for my website :(

I see that by default [it is fetched](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-auto-ads/0.1/ad-network-config.js#L96) from some DFP/AdSense API, but I could not find any way to edit that configuration from UI or whatsoever.

Is there any way to edit that configuration to get auto-ads working with AdSense?